# Ascii code for less than or equal to

Tags: html, ascii, asciiencoding

I cant find it on google.

What is the ASCII code for less than or equal to. I need this `≤` to be outputted in my browser

Comment: That symbol is not in the ASCII code table.

Comment: OK any way so i can use it in my browser ?..thinking of using it as an image

Comment: You could copy and paste the symbol above...

Comment: Alternatively, then HTML entity is `&#8804;`

Comment: @NicoBurns perfect..please post it as an answer..ill accept !

Comment: Forget ASCII. ASCII is so 1990. Think in Unicode. :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The character `≤` isn't in the ASCII table. However, there are several ways to embed it in HTML.

Firstly, using HTML entities: either `&le;`, `&#8804;`, or `&#x2264`. Just place this code in your HTML where you want the `≤` symbol to be.

Alternatively, ensure that your html file is `utf8` encoded, and include the meta tag `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` in the `<head>` of your document. You can then copy and paste the `≤` character directly into your document.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `&le;` for ( ≤ ) or `&ge;` ( ≥ )

Answer (score 8):

according to this [documentation](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2264/index.htm).

```
HTML Entity (decimal)   &#8804;
HTML Entity (hex)   &#x2264;
HTML Entity (named) &le;
```

Answer (score 4):

ALT-243 = ≤
ALT-242 = ≥

ASCII is very handy.

Answer (score 1):

That character isn't in the ASCII table. You may want to look into [Unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2264/index.htm).

Answer (score 1):

I always just underline <  and > which are standard keyboard characters.  It may be a little clugey, but it works, and it saves remembering numbers.
Frank