# In VBA, find n such that Chr(n) is greater than or equal to

Tags: vba, ascii, chr

Is there an *n* such that Chr(*n*) in Word VBA gives the greater than or equal to sign? Like Chr(150) is an m-dash (subtraction sign)?

Comment: Apparently `>=` is not in the ASCII table. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140003/ascii-code-for-less-than-or-equal-to)

Comment: @tospig ASCII is not relevant to VBA. `Chr()` uses the current ANSI codepage, which would be Windows-1252 or the like. `ChrW()` uses Unicode/UTF-16 code-units.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The character value code for greater than or equal is reached with ChrW, which accesses the Unicode character set, and the value is ChrW(&H2265)

Comment: I've just tried `ChrW(&H2265)` in Word and it gave me the equals (`=`) symbol only

Comment: How are you entering it?  "Selection.TypeText (ChrW(&H2265))" inserts the correct character for me.

Comment: Fascinating. Works now.

Comment: @khargushoghli feel free to mark this as "answered".

Comment: I will do so. Sorry, new to this, but need guidance on how to do that. 
BUT I'm a little concerned. I used the exact identical program before posting this question here because it failed.

Comment: @khargushoghli To mark a question as answered, click the big check mark next to the the answer.