# DOMPDF replaces "≤" by "?"

Tags: php, dompdf

I am generating pdfs with DOMPDF library but It is not properly handling the symbol "≤". In the pdf output appears an "?"

I have read other StackOverflow questions and I already have the

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

inside the `<head>` block.

I am using these fonts:

```
body 
{
   font-family:  "Helvetica","Arial","sans-serif";
   font-size:12px;
   color:gray;
   margin: 0px;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: This is probably a font issue. Are you sure the font you're using in your PDF includes the `≤` character? Try using one of the DejaVu fonts or some other font with good support for Unicode and see if that helps.

Comment: This might be either a font issue or encoding issue. Which font are you using? And, regardless of the meta tag, in which encoding is this document encoded?

Comment: The [Unicode How-To](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/UnicodeHowTo) might help.

Comment: I am using  "Helvetica","Arial","sans-serif":

Comment: Do you know any font that support this character? I have read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140003/ascii-code-for-less-than-or-equal-to but i don't know if it is the only option I have

Comment: If you're using 0.6.0 or newer you can, as mentioned by Chris, try one of the DejaVu fonts such as DejaVu Sans, e.g. `<span style="font-family: DejaVu Sans, sans-serif;">≤</span>`.

Comment: Off topic, but there should be no quotes around the `sans-serif`. It's a keyword, not a font name. Only font names should have quotes. (This won't be the solution to the problem though.)

Comment: BrianS I am using Arial that has the ≤ character.